# How to calculate Cook's distance for `lm.ridge` objects in R

Tags: r, regression, cooks-distance

How can I calculate Cook's distance for `lm.ridge` objects?

I first created a `glmnet` object and carried out ridge regression finding suitable shrinkage parameter. After that, I am calculating the beta values:

```r
object<-cv.glmnet(as.matrix(indp_data),response_data,type.measure = "mse")
fit_lm<-MASS:::lm.ridge(formula,data,lambda = seq(object$lambda.min,0.1,len=10),model=TRUE)
  whichIsBest <- which.min(fit_lm$GCV)
  gcv_est<-data.frame(coef(fit_lm)[whichIsBest,])
  row.names(gcv_est)[1]<-"Intrecept"
  colnames(gcv_est)[1] <- "Estimates"

  Beta_Values<-as.matrix(gcv_est)[-1,]
```

All variables are of class numeric. I have calculated the residual by subtracting fitted values from the observed. But how can I calculate Cook's distance from here?

Comment: First you need a method, then you can worry about implementing it: [Sensitivity analysis with an extension of Cook’s distance in ridge regression](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjss1970/24/2/24_2_221/_pdf)